# Get joined data in result for Solr Join Query

Tags: join, solr, relational

I have the following json files:

```
[{
 "entity_id":"A1",
 "entity_desc":"cat",
  "relation_id": "A2",
 "relation_type":"kind of"
  },

{
 "entity id":"A2",
 "entity_desc":"Animal",
  "relation_id": "A9",
  "relation_type":"xyz"
} ,
]
```

I have indexed them by solr and now I want to use the join query to get the result:

```
cat "is kind of" Animal.
```

How to map the `relation_id` in document `1` to `relation_id` in document `2`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I meant how to map relation_id in document 1 to entity_id in document 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get results from both entities.
You can only restrict your query by the joined entities.

Here a quotation from the [solr wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join):

> Joins in Solr are not really equivalent to
>   SQL Joins because no information about the table being joined "from"
>   is carried forward into the final result.
>   A more appropriate SQL analogy would be an "inner query".